How to do matrix multiplication under numpy in higher dimensions?
Under numpy I want to perform a "usual" matrix multiplication like this:
C=A*B
where
A is a "2D-kind" Matrix, but each matrix element has shape (1,5)
and
B is a "1D-kind" Vector, but each vector element element has shape (20,5)
The result
C shall be a "1D-kind" Vector, but each vector element element again has shape (20,5)

I tried to produce the elements C1 and C2 of C manually:
>>> A.shape
(2, 2, 1, 5)
>>> B.shape
(2, 20, 5)
>>> C0 = A[0,0]*B[0]+A[0,1]*B[1]
>>> C0.shape
(20, 5)
>>> C1 = A[1,0]*B[0]+A[1,1]*B[1]
>>> C1.shape
(20, 5)
>>>

Broadcasting (1,5) from A with (20,5) of B works as expected.
However, I was not able to find out, how this can be written like a matrix multiplication:
C = np.matmul(A, B)

Of course this doesn't work because numpy can't know what indices I want to sum over. But I guess that some simple "numpythonic" solution must exist...

A*B is NOT the "usual" matrix multiplication (which would be A @ B or A.dot(B)), it's element wise multiplication. Which do you actually want?

Also please create a [mre] with actual expected values

In any case the solution will likely involve np.einsum

You can use einsum:
C = np.einsum('ij...,j...->i...', A, B)

This is a contraction of the second dimension of A with the first dimension of B.  The remaining dimensions are carried along for the ride.
An example in an ipython session:
In [114]: rng = np.random.default_rng(8779780912870439733)

In [115]: A = rng.integers(0, 5, size=(2, 2, 1, 5))

In [116]: B = rng.integers(0, 5, size=(2, 20, 5))

In [117]: C = np.einsum('ij...,j...->i...', A, B)

In [118]: C.shape
Out[118]: (2, 20, 5)

In [119]: C0 = A[0,0]*B[0]+A[0,1]*B[1]

In [120]: C1 = A[1,0]*B[0]+A[1,1]*B[1]

In [121]: np.all(C[0] == C0)
Out[121]: True

In [122]: np.all(C[1] == C1)
Out[122]: True



This worked immediately. Thanks.

You can directly multiply A and B and sum the second dimension:
C = (A*B).sum(1)

# or
C = np.multiply(A, B).sum(1)

C.shape
# (2, 20, 5)

This gives the same output as your manual computation:
np.allclose(C[0], C0)
# True

np.allclose(C[1], C1)
# True

It works since numpy aligns the arrays on the right:
A (2, 2,  1, 5)
   |  |   |  |   # multiplication
B    (2, 20, 5)
B (1, 2, 20, 5)  # broadcasting
   |      |  |   # sum(1)
C (2,    20, 5)

Note that this is equivalent to a dot product using:
C = np.matmul(B[:, None].T, A.T).T[:, 0]

# or
C = (B[:, None].T@A.T).T[:, 0]


Your matmul can be explained as: B is changed from (2,20,5) to (2,1,20,5) to (5,20,1,2). A.T is (5,1,2,2).  Then dot on the last 2 dimensions to make (1,2), and broadcast on the leading 2, to make (5,20,1,2).  Transpose and take out the 1 to get (2,20,5).

Exact, thanks for detailing this @hpaulj, I showed this alternative to demonstrate that matmul can be used, although not really practical here.
